# Reporting on alert history

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

We are looking into building-out some reporting dashboards for use by product owners/etc that might not be familiar with Application Insights or Azure Monitor. We would like to display a list of historical alerts by type as well as some basic aggregations. We see where we can display this information (somewhat) from within Azure Monitor, but we do not see how we can actually surface this information on a dashboard within Azure.

I have found [this API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/alertsmanagement/alerts/getall), which seems to retrieve the data, but we are not looking to develop a custom solution.

Comment: Maybe [Azure Monitor Workbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/workbooks-overview) can help with that. It allows you to build (interactive) dashboards based on data in App Insights and Log Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

I hope [Serverless360](https://www.serverless360.com/signup?utm_source=Stackoverflow&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=categoury-q-%26-a) will be of great fit to your requirements where you will be able to display the historical alerts by type as well as with some advanced aggregations. You can easily set up the powerful dashboards and which can be easily handled by product owners (doesn't necessarily to be familiar with Azure Monitor) to get a high level of insights.

Below is a sample of how a dashboard would look like [image: Serverless360 historical alerts dashboard]